# Save pipe output as variable

Tags: angular, pipe

Is there a way to save the result of a piped expression into a variable for to use if a condition has been satisfied?

```
<div class="mat-caption" *ngIf="(myDate | daysSinceSomeEvent) > 0">Days since event {{ myDate | daysSinceSomeEvent}}</div>
```

becomes something like

```
<div class="mat-caption" *ngIf="(myDate | daysSinceSomeEvent) as result > 0">Days since event {{result}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your html in an Ng container that contains an ngIf that aliases the result for reuse.

```
<ng-container *ngIf=“(myDate | daysSinceSomeEvent) as result”>
  <div class="mat-caption" *ngIf="result > 0">
    Days since event {{result}}
  </div>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always inject the pipe through the constructor of your component and use it:

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {

    elapsedDays: number

    private _yourDate: Date
    @Input()
    set yourDate(v: Date) {
        this._yourDate = v;
        this.elapsedDays = this.daysSinceSomeEvent.transform(v)
    }
    get yourDate(): Date {
        return this._yourDate
    }

    constructor(private daysSinceSomeEvent: ElapsedTimePipe) {
    }
}
```

You can also get rid of the property getter and setter if you don't plan to pass multiple values as an input and move the logic into your `ngOnInit` block

Then in your template simply use the `elapsedDays` or `result` variable